# UTF8 database text not working on cakephp3

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0

I upgrade my application from CakePHP 2.7.7 to CakePHP 3.1.5

The old app (Cake 2) is working perfectly with `UFT-8` encoding. But on CakePHP 3 `UTF-8` text which is comming from mysql db is not showing correctly.

I changed the encoding on `app.php` file and also change the db encoding config.

What can be the reason for wrong encoding after updating from CakePHP 2 to 3?

Comment: i am updating on cakephp 3.1.5 and lower version is 2.7.7

Answer (score 0):

If the Unicode runes are coming back garbled in some cases, try changing your character set to "utf8mb4" instead.

It's important to note that on MySQL, the "utf8" character set does not actually encode the full UTF-8 set of Unicode runes. This is for historical reasons (specifically, UTF-8 wasn't entirely defined when MySQL implemented it).

The "utf8mb4" character set encodes the full Unicode rune set and most of the time is actually the one you want.

All that said, you must look carefully at all the character set settings for your connection. PHP and MySQL have very finicky character set interactions, and if PHP isn't properly telling MySQL the character set it wants to use, things can break even if you've done all the above correctly.

For more info about PHP and MySQL character sets:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

This is my favourite resource on "utf8" vs "utf8mb4":
https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Comment: You are correct but here problem is : i am using same configuration (mysql & php) in cakephp 2.7 but  with this configuration  , different language text not working on cakephp3.0